# Audio src saved on cookie but not playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have 5 songs in a playlist and when i click on next song then i see current src has saved on cookie but when i reload browser the current src not auto playing.In browser console network tab - initiator i've found `other` .

```
var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var runsrc = $.cookie("savesrc");
function update() {
    if(!played){
         if(runsrc){
           song.addEventListener("canplay",function(){runsrc&&(song.src=runsrc,runsrc=null);
            });
            song.play();
            played = true;
            }
       else {
            song.play();
            played = true;
            }
        }
        else {
        $.cookie('savesrc', song.src);
        }
      }
  setInterval(update,0);
```

Comment: what jQuery cookie extention are you using? if a cookie is not set it will return **undefined**, so your if should be : `if (typeof runsrc !== 'undefined')` can you please add a `console.log("hey");` inside your condition slightly before the `song.play()`? In that way we can understand if the problem is related to that if or not.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie @briosheje

Comment: cookie set working. but song not playing and nothig error in console only get `other` in browser console network tab - initiator. @briosheje

Comment: I suspect the problem may be related to the canplay event. First of all, change your set interval second parameter to 1 (1 millisecond), then, insert `song.play();` **inside** your canplay callback function, right after: `runsrc&&(song.src=runsrc,runsrc=null);`

Comment: Thanks bro working but i have a question